# How to change the counter variable value of for loop inside the loop in Kotlin?

Tags: loops, kotlin, for-loop, variables, variable-assignment

I'm new to Kotlin and for practice i'm converting my Java codes into Kotlin.

While doing that I'm facing one issue i.e., i'm unable to change the counter value inside the for loop. It actually says the variable is `val`.

```
for (i in 0..tokens.size){
    // some code
    if (memory[pointer]!=0)
        i=stack.peek() // error here showing : val cannot be reassigned
}
```

I really want the counter variable to be changed inside the loop. Is there any other way that i can achieve this without any error in Kotlin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that `for...in` loop is not a loop with counter, but a foreach loop - even if you use range to iterate (well, at least conceptually, because internally it is in fact optimized to a loop with counter). You can't jump to another item in the array/list, because `for` does not really "understand" the logic behind iterating. Even if you would be able to modify the value of `i`, then with next iteration it would reset to the next item.

You need to use `while` instead:

```kotlin
var i = 0
while (i < tokens.size) {
    if (memory[pointer]!=0)
        i=stack.peek()

    i++
}
```

Also note that your original code contained an off-by-one bug. In last iteration `i` would become `tokens.size` which is probably not what you need.

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin `val` variables are equivalent of Java's `final`, which means once assigned they cannot be changed. Use `var` instead when you want the variable to be reassigned. If possible, you should keep `val` to prevent accidental reassignment.

Example:

```kotlin
var a = 5

a = 4 // works

val b = 5

b = 4 // compiler error!
```

**EDIT**

The variable in for loop is treated as `val` by default, and you cannot change it. In order to achieve a loop with jumps, you need to use `while` loop instead.

Comment: read the question again, you don't have a specific var declaration when you are in a loop

Comment: I have edited the answer

Comment: That's not an exception. It's a compiler error.

Answer (score 1):

kotlin loop variables(in your case `i`) are implicitly declared using `val`, so you can't reassign them. your only option is to use a `while` loop and update a variable declared outside the loop.

From [Kotlin language spec](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/statements.html#for-loop-statements)

> The for-loop is actually an overloadable syntax form with the
> following expansion:
>
> `for(VarDecl in C) Body` is the same as
>
> ````
> when(val $iterator = C.iterator()) {
>     else -> while ($iterator.hasNext()) {
>                 val VarDecl = __iterator.next()
>                 <... all the statements from Body>
>             } } ```
> ````